# Reuse Viewbox resource

Tags: wpf

Running Visual Studio 2017 and targeting .NET 4.6.1. Consider the `XAML` below. In the XAML editor you see both circles, but when running the application only the second one is shown.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Viewbox x:Key="MyBox" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Ellipse Width="4" Height="4" Fill="Red"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Width="100" Content="{StaticResource MyBox}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Width="100" Content="{StaticResource MyBox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

How can you reuse a `Viewbox` resource?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `x:Shared` attribute of it to false:

```
<Viewbox x:Key="MyBox" x:Shared="False" Stretch="Uniform">
```